# Can moderators post as other users?

Tags: support, moderators

I left a comment on [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33286/15982)  suggesting it is a duplicate of a question the asker linked to. I didn't include the link as it was in the question. When I checked back later there was a second comment saying

> Possible duplicate of [link]

apparently by me, but I didn't write it.

Can moderators post such comments as other users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can moderators post such comments as other users?

No. Moderators cannot post or take action as another user.
We can however *edit* comments left by other users (and occasionally do so when the comment runs afoul of our [Be Nice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy but contains valuable information).

[As kevin pointed out](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3136/64) the "Possible Duplicate Of…" comment is an automatic comment.
If the question is closed as a duplicate the automatic comment should be deleted by the system.

Answer (score 6):

That comment is automatically generated by the system when you click the "Vote to Close" button while selecting a duplicated question as a reason.

Comment: and automatically up-voted when others cast VTC